# Point-Free Function using Typescript fp-ts

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I'm learning FP using fp-ts and as an exercise to learn how to use `RTE`, I'm trying to (re)implement fetch-fp-ts. Here's what I've got so far:

```js
import type { Request, Response } from "fetch-fp-ts";
import * as F from "fetch-fp-ts";
import * as E from "fp-ts/Either";
import * as R from "fp-ts/Reader";
import * as RTE from "fp-ts/ReaderTaskEither";
import * as TE from "fp-ts/TaskEither";
import { flow, pipe } from "fp-ts/function";
import nodeFetch from "node-fetch";

type E<A> = E.Either<Error, A>;
type TE<A> = TE.TaskEither<Error, A>;
type RTE<R, A> = RTE.ReaderTaskEither<R, Error, A>;

export interface FetchEnv {
  fetch: (...args: Request) => TE<Response<number>>;
}

export const send: (r: Request) => RTE<FetchEnv, Response<number>> = r => {
  return pipe(
    R.ask<FetchEnv>(),
    R.map(({ fetch }) => fetch(...r)),
  );
};
```

Specifically here, I'd like to understand what's the best API for `send`. For example how can I make the `send` function point-free? What's the FP way of designing the `send` function API?

Note: I understand that pushing too much for point-free is not recommended due to less readability, but here I'm trying to learn how the data should flow from one function to another.
To make things concrete, here's an example of using send function:

```js
// This is a function that gets an AWS SNS subscription message
// and confirms the subscription by calling the given URL!
export const subscriptionConfirmHttpHandler =
  (env: FetchEnv) =>
  (msg: Subscription): TE<undefined> => {
    return pipe(
      env,
      Http.sendGET(msg.SubscribeURL), // `send` with GET verb!
      TE.mapLeft(SubscriptionConfirmationFailedError.causedBy),
      TE.map(_ => undefined), // discard response!
    );
  };
```

For example here there's two pieces of input; `env` and `msg`. What's the correct (FP) way of defining this function; should `env` be first or `msg`? Why? Is there a rule of thumb or something that can help with designing the API?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using ReaderTaskEither, then you need to put the `env` last. 
`RTE<R, E, A>` is simply equivalent to `(env: R) => TE<E, A>` in the end. This will allow you to compose things more easily if you're using RTE everywhere else as well